# default shell environment when remote compiling with emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, compilation, tramp

I want to compile a C++ project on a remote machine. This Project is using some C++11 features but the default compiler is gcc 4.6.3, so I have an entry in my .profile which adds the module gcc 4.7.2 to use this features. With a remote shell I have no problem compiling with a simple make command, but emacs M-x compile function doesn't work, because it says the gcc compiler doesn't know the -std=c++11 option.
That means the remote shell, which is set up, doesn't add the module and I have no idea how I can fix this.

So I'm asking you for help!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing you should put in your makefile, since it's project-dependent.
Something like this:

```
CXX = g++ -std=c++0x
```

Adjust accordingly if you're not using something other than automake.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the initial problem. This gcc version (4.6.3) may know c++0x, but if I need some other features in other versions I couldn't load them remotely.
The flags are all set in the makefile just with `-std=c++11` instead.

Comment: Fine, re-define CXX in makefile instead. It decides which gcc to use